# Aggregate duplicate members of an object in C# using LINQ / Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, aggregate-functions

I have a job to aggregate companies employees existing in 2 different databases using LINQ, the criteria is to find companies with the same name then find departments in these companies with the same name too then merge all employees into a new company object.

I have all companies from the 2 databases in one `List<Company>`, is their a way to use the `Aggregate` function to merge companies with the same name, then find departments with same name and merge all their employees? using the Aggregate function seems to be easy to merge "1 level" of data, I'm struggling to go into 3 levels of aggregation (Company>Department>Employee)

Example of my `List<Company> AllCompanies` object:

```
Company       Department      Employees   Source
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
ABC Inc    |  Sales       | Sam         | DB1
           |              | Laura       |
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
ABC Inc    |  Sales       | Joe         | DB2
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
ABC Inc    |  Sales       | Joe         | DB1
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
ABC Inc    |  IT          | Matt        | DB2
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
XYZ Inc    |  Sales       | Steve       | DB1
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
XYZ Inc    |  Sales       | Steve       | DB2 
-----------|--------------|-------------|---------
XYZ Inc    |  HR          | Mark        | DB2
```

I'm trying to convert the above to:

```
Company       Department      Employees
-----------|--------------|-------------
ABC Inc    |  Sales       | Sam
           |              | Laura
           |              | Joe
           |--------------|-------------
           |  IT          | Matt
-----------|--------------|-------------
XYZ Inc    |  Sales       | Steve
           |--------------|-------------
           |  HR          | Mark
```

For the sake of this example my match criteria is the name only.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to draw the tables above, pretty neat, but apart from that I didn't try anything cause I didn't know how to do it, which is why I come here seeking for an answer in the first place but thanks for trying to answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 from c in allCompanies
 group c by c.Company into departments
 select new {
    Company = departments.Key,
    Departments = from d in departments
                  group d by d.Department into employees
                  select new {
                      Department = employees.Key,
                      Employees = employees.Select(e => e.Employees)
                                           .Distinct()
                  }
 }
```